# Batch Script to allow Network DTC Access

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003

Can I allow Network DTC Access using a batch script on Windows Server 2003 machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

As per Microsoft TechNet article ["Enable Network Access Securely for MS DTC"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753620%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), this is controlled by the registry value `NetworkDtcAccess` under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security`.

You can enable it (and restart the service) like so:

```
reg.exe add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security /v NetworkDtcAccess /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
net stop msdtc
net start msdtc
```

The registry values for most of the other options shown on your screenshot are documented in the TechNet article.